# Limiting UIPinchGestureRecognizer Zoom Levels Objective C to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, catransform3d, catransformlayer

iOS 10.2 Swift 3.0

Trying to translate this piece of code from Paul Solt blog. Fixed by SO poster, updated code!

http://paulsolt.com/blog/2011/03/limiting-uipinchgesturerecognizer-zoom-levels

Sample Code

```
- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
// Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
}

if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
[gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer     valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

// Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.0;
const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]); // new     scale is in the range (0-1)
newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
[gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor     for the next pinch gesture call
}
}
```

Almost done, but can not seem to find a reference to the CATransform key used here for Swift 3.0. My code ...

```
if sender.state == .began {
        // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
        lastScale = sender.scale
    }

    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {

        // UPDATED
        currentScaleX = self.image2P.transform.scaleX
        currentScaleY = self.image2P.transform.scaleY


        self.image2P.transform = self.image2P.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)


        // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
        let kMaxScale:CGFloat = 2.0;
        let kMinScale:CGFloat = 1.0;

        var newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - sender.scale) // new scale is in the range (0-1)
        newScale = min(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScaleX)
        newScale = max(newScale, kMinScale / currentScaleY)
        self.image2P.transform = self.image2P.transform.scaledBy(x: newScale, y: newScale)

        lastScale = sender.scale  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
    }
```

Comment: use `self.image2P.layer.transform.scale` instead of `value()`.

Comment: Sadly Sachin this doesn't seem to exist :)

Comment: What is not available.

Comment: self.image2P.layer.transform.scale doesn't exist? Only m values under transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store `xScale` and `yScale` separately because generally speaking there is no guarantee they are equal.

```
extension CGAffineTransform {
    var scaleX: CGFloat {
        return (a > 0 ? 1 : -1) * sqrt (a*a + c*c)
    }

    var scaleY: CGFloat {
        return (d > 0 ? 1 : -1) * sqrt (b*b + d*d)
    }
}
```

These extension methods will work return correct scale factors even if your view is also **rotated** and/or **translated**:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.2).rotated(by: .pi/3.0).translatedBy(x: 50, y: 30)
print("scaleX = \(view.transform.scaleX), scaleY = \(view.transform.scaleY)")
```

Output:

> scaleX = 1.5, scaleY = 1.2

It may be not obvious, but `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` properties are elements of the `transform` matrix. You can find more details in [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD). Also you can find math details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/extracting-rotation-scale-values-from-2d-transformation-matrix). Just be aware that `b` and `c` element names are swapped in these two sources.